# Excute a command in Linux when system reboot

Tags: linux, mongodb

Looking for an option to run the below Mongodb command whenever the Linux system reboots.

mongos --configdb "mg-xxx-cfg-1:27017,mg-xxx-cfg-2:27017,mg-xxx-cfg-3:27017"

Answer (score 1):

Install it as a service. Usually when you [install MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-on-linux/) then a `mongod` service is installed automatically. Take this as template and modify `mongod` to `mongos`.

Instead of command line options I suggest a [config file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) (e.g. `mongos --config /etc/mongos.conf`)

Then enable the service with `sudo systemctl enable mongos` (command may be different on your Linux)

My `/etc/systemd/system/mongos.service` file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Router
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongos.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongos $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid
Type=forking

# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false
# Recommended limits for for mongod as specified in
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the `/etc/mongos.conf` file could be this:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  logRotate: reopen
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongos.log

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true

security:
  keyFile: /home/mongod/.mongo.key

sharding:
  configDB: mg-xxx-cfg-1:27017,mg-xxx-cfg-2:27017,mg-xxx-cfg-3:27017
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility could be to edit `/etc/crontab` according to [crontab(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html). Read also about [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

You probably want to add a line like

```
@reboot /usr/bin/mongos --configdb "mg-xxx-cfg-1:27017,mg-xxx-cfg-2:27017,mg-xxx-cfg-3:27017"
```

You may need to write your own shell script (containing the `mongos` command, and invoked by `/etc/crontab`)

You could (if your system is `systemd` based) use [systemd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemd.1.html) utilities.

You could also use (if it is installed) the Linux [batch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/batch) command.

And of course, you could run `batch` from `/etc/crontab`. Be careful about [$PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (it is different when running a crontab job). See [exec(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) and [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)

Read also documentation of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) and *Advanced Linux Programming*. Since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), you are allowed to download and improve its source code.

Comment: Thanks for your response, do I have to add '&' at the end to get the command running in the background?

Answer (score -1):

Try using Startup Applications, or Gnome Tweaks. What DE are you using? What distro? These will work on any Ubuntu or Gnome OS, I believe. 
Can I have some clarification on why this post is no longer correct? Is there something wrong with the solution?